# LESS compiler magically adds unwanted classes to my selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

This is the important part of my LESS file:

```
input.ng-invalid { 
  color: #e74c3c;
  border-color: #e74c3c;
}
```

It compiles into this:

```
input.ng-invalid .form-control {
  color: #e74c3c;
  border-color: #e74c3c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/118uS4RciQYVPa5KH6oU

The `form-control` class is from Bootstrap and wouldn't break the selector if LESS didn't insert a space (`input.ng-invalid.form-control` works just fine)

**The problem is that the browser is looking for the children of `input` with the class `form-control`. Apparently, there are no childrens of `input` in my HTML.**

Is there a setting in bootstrap's LESS files that binds the `form-control` class to every `input`?

Comment: Can't you just add `.form-control;` globally to all inputs? S.th. like `input { .form-control; color:red; }` ?

Comment: I will explain a little further in my original question

Comment: please include your actual LESS source.

Comment: [Download LESS files](http://www.xup.in/dl,20180334/less.7z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look at the zip package you provided and there your `input.ng-invalid` is defined as (`selfmade.less:L97`):

```
input.ng-invalid {
    .form-control-validation(@brand-danger; @brand-danger);
}
```

which is expected to compile to what you actually get (i.e. appending *nested classes* defined within `.form-control-validation`). This is just what this mixin is supposed to do.

#### -

> Is there a setting in bootstrap's LESS files that binds the `form-control` class to every input?

I can't see any (at least in Bootstrap 3.1.1), so I can only suggest **the following trick**:

```
.danger_ {
    .form-control-validation
        (@brand-danger, @brand-danger);
}

input.ng-invalid.form-control
    :extend(.danger_ .form-control all) {}
```

which will compile to [this css](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9334384#file-22148167-css) (assuming bs-3.1.1).

#### -

Alternatively there's `.has-error` class which you can extend the same way:

```
input.ng-invalid.form-control
    :extend(.has-error .form-control all) {}
```

and get a bit more compact output but with slightly different colours (`@state-danger-text` instead of `@brand-danger`).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but an investigation of your problem which doesn't fit in the comments box. I did't go through your set of less files since I don't have a 7z uncompressor here, but maybe I can give you some ideas to help you fix the problem or hack it.

One way of obtaining a contextual relationship like this:

```
input.ng-invalid .form-control { ... }
```

Is having a block like this somewhere in your Less files:

```
input.ng-invalid {
   ...
   .form-control { ... }
   ...
}
```

Now that association might happen through a mixin so you probably won't find that exact pattern above, but you might find want to discover where .form-control is declared (a mixin, perhaps).

Now if you want this:

```
input.ng-invalid.form-control { ...}
```

and you a block like the one I showed above, you can add a `&` before the `.form-control` selector so that instead of obtaining a contextual relationship from the nesting blocks, you add a class. The `&` represents the selectors from the parent block. It would be something like:

```
input.ng-invalid {
   ...
   &.form-control { ... }
   ...
}
```

See if you discover where `.form-control` is defined and try it out.

(Be aware that if other parts of your code use this mixin or selector, they may not work as before - this was just an analysis of a possible solution using Less and not the Bootstrap framework; add a `bootstrap` tag to your question and you might attract some Bootstrap specialists who might have a better solution.)